# When I append an item to a list with existing items in there, it just overides it and replaces the existing item

Tags: python, postgresql, discord.py

My problem is when I use the command once, it gives me a fish, but if I do it again, it replaces the previous fish with the newest one. It should be adding itself to the list, no overwriting it. Below, kind is the list. Every time I use the command, a fish is supposed to be appended to that list

```
async def fish(ctx, *, msg: str):
    level = 1
    storage = []
    cash = 0
    kind = []
    fishes = 0

    name = ctx.author.name
    guild_id = ctx.guild.id
    user_id = ctx.author.id
    large_chance = ['Carp', 'Salmon', 'Frog']
    medium_chance = ['Catfish', 'Eel', 'Large Bass']
    small_chance = ['Angelfish', 'Blobfish', 'Shark']

    cursor.execute("SELECT fish FROM fishing WHERE user_id = %s AND guild_id = %s",
                   (user_id, guild_id))
    result1 = cursor.fetchone()
    if result1 is None:
        cursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO fishing (name, user_id, guild_id, fish, kind) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
            (name, user_id, guild_id, fishes, kind))
        conn.commit()
    elif result1 is not None:
        if msg == 'fish':
            y = random.randint(0, 100)
            if y >= 30:
                small = random.choice(large_chance)
                embed = discord.Embed(title='Fishing Game',
                                      color=ctx.author.color)
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
                embed.add_field(name='You caught a common fish', value=f'You caught a {small}')
                embed.add_field(name="Worth:", value="$5")
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                kind.append(small)
                fishes = result1[0] + 1
                await ctx.send(kind)
                cursor.execute("UPDATE fishing SET kind = %s, fish = %s WHERE user_id = %s AND guild_id = %s",
                               (kind, fishes, user_id, guild_id))
                conn.commit()
```

Comment: maybe you should only post the relevant code to your problem and not the whole code. just pinpoint your problem. only post the code block where you're facing a problem.

Comment: you should always provide a [mcve] also, its not very clear what your problem is. it helps if you provide examples

Comment: What is the schema for the table fishes? In particular what are the data types?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver the data types are as follows:

name: text, 
user_id: bigint,
guild_id: bigint,
fish: int,
kind: text

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here. The first is the @Silas Hayes-Williams mentions, that is you are resetting `kind` to an empty list every time you run the function. So you will only have one kind of fish in the list at a time. The second issue is that you are storing a list in a text field. For what all that means see [List](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html?highlight=type#adapt-list) in the psycopg2 docs. The short version is:

```
['Carp'] 
# Becomes
'{Carp}'
```

on retrieval unless you do something like:

`cur.execute("select kind::varchar[] from fishing")`

which will result in a list being returned that you can work with. The last thing is you have to put some code into the above that retrieves the existing `kind`  for the user(per @Silas Hayes-Williams) and use that to append to.

Answer (score 0):

You're redefining `kind` everytime you run the command. Instead try reading the users current `kind` from the database you're using and setting that to a variable to use

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT kind FROM fishing WHERE user_id = %s AND guild_id = %s",
                   (user_id, guild_id))
kind = cursor.fetchone()
```

Using this instead of `kind=[]` should hopefully work!

Comment: See my answer below for why the above needs modification.

Comment: @Silas Hayes-Williams 
Hey! Thanks much, but it says you can't append to tuples. I know they're immutable, but how would I change that? Apparently the cursor.fetchone() is a tuple..

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks for that! I haven't had much experience storing lists in databases before

Comment: @HankHill. Yes psycopg2 will return a tuple(fetchone()) or a list of tuples(fetchall()) by default[cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html). That can be changed by using a different [cursor factory](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html?highlight=cursor%20factory) but that is not to help with the underlying issue that you are storing a Python list as a Postgres array in a text field. One solution is what I show in my answer. The other is to make the ```kind``` field an varchar array type field